# Flex Mobile: TabbedViewNavigatorApplication with tab on top (Android style)?

Tags: apache-flex, air, tabbar, mobile-application, flex4.6

Working on an Android app with FB 4.6, I would like to have the **tabbar on top of the screen**.

Moreover, I would like to have the so called **'TitleBar', at the bottom of the screen** and the possibility to change it's visibility. In some case, I want the titlebar to be visible, in other case, not.

I found this resource, [Flex 4.5 Mobile Development – Tabs on Top](http://devgirl.org/2011/06/14/flex-4-5-mobile-development-tabs-on-top/), but, AFAIU, it's applicable to FB 4.5, not 4.6.

So, How can I achieve this in a FB 4.6 mobile app?

EDIT: Solved!

Works fine with FB 4.6 indeed. For TitleBar, just do the same kind of trick with spark.skins.mobile.ViewNavigatorSkin :-)

Comment: All those instructions found at blog for Flex 4.5 SDK, are still valid for 4.6 as well, just tried at my local setup.

Comment: Hi JabbyPanda, I can't believe I missed that. I supposed I somehow open the wrong file. really weird.. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine with FB 4.6 indeed. For TitleBar, just do the same kind of trick with spark.skins.mobile.ViewNavigatorSkin :-)